# Angle Animation with CSS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if this question has been asked before (it probably has), but I want to animate an image object with CSS / jQuery - once - when the user scrolls to a certain height by, say, 90 degrees.

By once, I mean that even if the user scrolls back up and hits the stipulated height again, the animation won't restart itself.

Is this possible? How do I go about doing it? Which method is better? Or is it a combination of both?

Note: I know that I'll have to execute the scrollTop function to check for height - I'm asking which would be more efficient - CSS or jQuery.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: I've seen that before, but performance wise, compared to css? Especially on mobile...

Comment: It uses css unless the browser doesn't support it

Comment: Ahh, I see. That's interesting.

Comment: Mark my answer as correct if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Check it out, it checks if the browser supports css rotation and uses it, or if not, uses either canvas or SVG.